# How to react on file in path with property in maven?

Tags: maven-2

I want to use some plugin executions of my maven project only when a certain file does not exist. The path to this file can change - that's why it must contain a property (and please correct me if that's not the case). A good way would be to use profile activation with the file, but because the path has a property this doesn't work (as stated in the [Maven 'Introduction to build profiles'](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)).

That said, the question is: Do you know a way to achieve the desired behaviour only with one pom?

Of course the enforcer plugin offers a limited way of reacting on files but I don't want to necessarily fail or interrupt the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really much you can do. Here are your options:

1. Live with the restrictions. The only way you can configure the file path is through a system property (user properties are evaluated using profiles, not the other way around):

   ```
   <profile>
       <id>foobar</id>
       <activation>
           <file><exists>${file.path}</exists></file>
       </activation>
   </profile>

   mvn -Dfile.path=some/path/file.txt clean install
   ```
2. Invoke the executions programmatically, e.g with the [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/). Either

   - write a custom plugin or
   - write a main class and call it from [Exec:Java](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) or
   - use an inline Groovy Script with [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home)

   Either one of the above options will have to behave as a dispatcher that invokes mojos using the invoker depending on evaluation of properties.

Comment: I didn't think of the difference between used defined and system properties - thank you for this answer!